# java: throw exception or error if a network call takes too long?

Tags: java

i have developed a method that makes a network http request and waits for the response. i now want to handle a scenario where if the http response takes longer then expected, i want to cancel/terminate that connectinn by throwing some kind of exception plus an error.

im not asking how to throw exceptions and errors, i know that, im just asking how i can some how time how long its taking for me to retrieve a http response?

psuedo below is something like this:

1. start some timer
2. make http request
3. wait for http request
4. if response doesnt get retrieved after X, throw error/exception.

Their has been cases where when i do make a http request it takes a minute or two before the jvm finally throws an exception but i wish to throw this exception quicker instead of the app freezing and waiting 3-4mins.

Thanks in advance

Im doing this for a android application so either android specific libs or java 5 libs should be sufficiant for an example on how to achieve this.

edit: here is how my http request code looks like using apache libs:

```
    import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


private HttpClient httpclient;
private HttpGet get;
private HttpPost post;

/**
     * POST request
     */
    private HttpResponseObject PostRequest() {

        //int response = 0;

        String responseBody = "";
        HttpResponseObject response = new HttpResponseObject();

        try {

            Log.d(TAG, "IN POST_REQUEST_METHOD");
            Log.d(TAG, "URL : " + url);

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();



            post = new HttpPost(url);


            ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(data.getBytes());
            entity.setChunked(true);

            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(post);

            HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


            if (resEntity != null) {
                // indicate that the content of this entity is no longer
                // required
                response.setResponseBody(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));

                Header[] header = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();

                Log.d(TAG, "httpResponse.getAllHeaders() = " + header[0].getName());
                response.setResponseHeader(httpResponse.getAllHeaders().toString());
                resEntity.consumeContent();
            }

            // release all recources from the httpClient object
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            response.setResponseCode(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() ) ;

            Log.d(TAG, "responseBody = " + response.getResponseBody());
            Log.d(TAG, "response code = " + response.getResponseCode());
            Log.d(TAG, "response header = " + response.getResponseHeader());

            return response;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "exception e  = " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240320/how-can-i-wrap-a-method-so-that-i-can-kill-its-execution-if-it-exceeds-a-specifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using HttpClient 4.0.x, then the way to control this kind of thing is by setting [connection parameters](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `java.net.HttpUrlConnection`? `HttpUrlConnection` is a subclass of `java.net.UrlConnection`, which has methods `setConnectTimeout(int)` and `setReadTimeout(int)`. Once these thresholds are exceeded on either `connect()` or `InputStream.read()`, then an `IOException` will be thrown.

Check out the Javadoc at...

[setConnectTimeout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29)

and

[setReadTimeout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29)

EDIT:
Ah, some code. I'm afraid I'm not that familiar with the org.apache.http package, but it looks like `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet` inherits from the interface `org.apache.http.client.methods.AbortableHttpRequest`, so you could use the method `setConnectionRequest(ClientConnectionRequest connRequest)` which has a method `getConnection (long timeout, TimeUnit tunit)`. Really, I'm just clutching at straws here - If you're only doing something basic with HTTP, I'd say go for `java.net.HttpUrlConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Future` variable and use the [`Future.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

> **... throwing some kind of exception plus an error**

I would like to advice you not to throw an `Error` if that's what you're talking about here.

From the documentation of `Error`:

> *An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates **serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch**.*

Comment: what i mean by error is to display an error message to the user. see my edit on my http request code and how it looks like