# How to run a method with timeout?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, concurrency

I'd like to execute a specific method with a timeout. The wrapper method should block as long as the timeout method is still running.

How could I best achieve this, preferably using `Spring`?

```
public boolean run() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        executeWithTimeout(); //how?
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("method could not complete");
        return false;
    }

    return true; //block as long as the method above is still running
}
```

Comment: A very elegant solution is to use the ExecutorService with Callable's and Futures, as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2275596/1296707

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time out method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982420/time-out-method-in-java)